# Elasticsearch create mapping issue

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I'm following this blog to implement autocomplete feature. I tried creating the exact mapping but stumbled upon some error.

Following is my intended mapping query.

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/blurays " -d'
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "nGram_filter": {
               "type": "nGram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20,
               "token_chars": [
                  "letter",
                  "digit",
                  "punctuation",
                  "symbol"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "nGram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "nGram_filter"
               ]
            },
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "movies": {
         "_all": {
            "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
         },
         "properties": {
            "addToCartUrl": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "no",
               "include_in_all": false
            },
            "format": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "mpaaRating": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed",
               "include_in_all": false
            },
            "price": {
               "type": "double",
               "include_in_all": false
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Following is the error that I'm getting:-

```
analyzer on field [_all] must be set when search_analyzer is set
```

I'm using the latest version of the ES, ie 2.3 and this was written 2 years back. I've just started learning ES. What can be the possible solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When defining the `_all` field you need to replace `index_analyzer` with `analyzer` as this has been [renamed in 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#_analyzer_mappings).

```
     "_all": {
        "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
     },
```

Agreed, the error message could be better, though.

Comment: Every mapping coming from `1.x` to `2.x` should be checked for `index_analyzer`.

Answer (score 0):

The index analyzer has been removed in elasticsearch 2.x.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#_analyzer_mappings